# How to set Flutter iPhone X Safe Area

Tags: dart, flutter

The reason I used Flutter for this project was to get both Android and iphone in 1 code base. The Android app looks good with the bottom nav bar hitting the on screen home.

The iphone version however runs into the slide up bar on the iphone X models.

Is there a way to solve this? I would take being able to adjust it, but I dont want a drop shadow, I just want it one solid color.

I used a SafeArea, and while it did fix it. it also caused the bar to move up and look weird.

```
bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
     child: bmnav.BottomNav(
      elevation: 9.0,
      index: _currentTab,
      iconStyle: bmnav.IconStyle(
          color: Colors.grey, onSelectColor: Colors.lightGreen),
      labelStyle: bmnav.LabelStyle(
          onSelectTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightGreen)),
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentTab = index;
        });
      },
      items: [
        bmnav.BottomNavItem(Customicons.main, label: "Home"),
        bmnav.BottomNavItem(Customicons.bible, label: "Bible"),
        bmnav.BottomNavItem(Customicons.sermons, label: "Sermons"),
        bmnav.BottomNavItem(FontAwesomeIcons.pray, label: "Prayer"),
        bmnav.BottomNavItem(Icons.more_horiz, label: "More"),
      ]),
),
```

This is what it looks like with and without the safe area. But what I am looking for is a sold look, basically like a large bottom nav bar.

[image][image]

Comment: Fix your attached images please.

Comment: may be you want to show what is bmnav.BottomNav ?

Comment: bmnav.bottomNav is the plugin that I am using that makes the bottom nav bar much better than the out of the box and a bit more customization.

Comment: so why don't you ask author of this plugin? obviously this plugin don't makes nav bar much better as you may see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return SafeArea(
  bottom: true,
  child: bmnav.BottomNav(),
)
```

Comment: Doing this leads to my 1st image. I am looking for that result, but not looking like its a card

Comment: It's really hard to help you without detailed examples of what you need because you said you're using a custom bottom nav bar.

Comment: I would like it to extend like the normal bottom nav bar. where it looks like one solid bar. The problem I was getting with the normal bottom nav bar is I wanted to customize the colors, and I did not want the items to grow when selected. Which is why i went with this one.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, SafeArea takes away layout flexibility.
I prefer to use different height bottom menu:

1. without a notch
2. with notch +20pixels

You can easily do it with package https://pub.dev/packages/iphone_has_notch
It is light and doesn't take any additional resources.

So, code could be as simple as:

```
height: IphoneHasNotch.hasNotch ? 88 : 68,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return Container(
  color:Colors.white,
  child:SafeArea(
  bottom: true,
  child: bmnav.BottomNav(),
 ),
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will give you the expected result. You can use this code to avoid card-like feel.

**EDITED :**

```
Align(child: SafeArea(
            bottom: true,
            child: bmnav.BottomNavItem(Customicons.main, label: "Home"), // Ur view at bottom
          ),
        ),
```

Or

```
 SafeArea(
            bottom: true,
            child: bmnav.BottomNavItem(Customicons.main, label: "Home"), // Ur view at bottom
          ),
```

Comment: I have tested in my app & it works as expected. May I know the reason for the downvote, plz.